# Which is the best practice in C# for type casting?

Tags: c#, .net

Which method is best practice to type casting and checking ?

```
Employee e = o as Employee;
if(e != null)
{
 //DO stuff
}
```

OR

```
if(o is Employee)
{
Employee e = (Employee) o;
 //DO stuff
}
```

Comment: Your question is primarily opinion based. I voted to close as the duplicate as I'm sure its more useful to you to see what the differences are to make your own decision

Comment: I always do `as`, it needs to get casted anyway.

Comment: My question is whether any performance difference is there ?
not the difference between is and as keyword.

Comment: Well then it depends on whether you expect o to be an employee or not, if it isn't then is can return quicker but if it is then as can probably cast quicker. Either way, [race the horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: Your question is nothing at all to do with performance. You just asked "which is best".

Comment: Best in the "performance" ?
I think  "good practice " cover permanence also. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Code analysis will probably issue a warning for the second snippet. So I would use the first. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182271.aspx

Comment: I can almost guarrantee this one line of code isn't going to be your codes bottleneck, hence why the only answers you could possibly get are opinions

Comment: This is almost a good question to me, it poses a very good and challenging point, but seems te reek of opinion based answers. there is often no *best* way overall to do things. there is often a fastest, or most efficient way, way of doing it though.

Comment: @TimothyGroote No, I disagree. There's a lot of things going on with casts in C# that make this a very valid question. In this case, the fastest way is also the most efficient way and the easiest way - which makes this a non-opinion based question. The main problem is that there's so much different things going on that most people have problems wrapping their heads around all the possible casts (also judging from the other answers that only scratch the basics). I've attempted to write down an answer that covers all the different variants of casts in c# to address this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

At least there are two possibilities for casting, one for type checking and a combination of both called pattern matching. Each has its own purpose and it depends on the situation:

#### [Hard cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/invocation-operator#cast-expression)

```
var myObject = (MyType)source;
```

You normally do that if you are absolutely sure if the given object is of that type. A situation where you use it, if you subscribed to an event handler and you cast the sender object to the correct type to work on that.

```
private void OnButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;

    button.Text = "Disabled";
    button.Enabled = false;
}
```

#### [Soft cast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/as)

```
var myObject = source as MyType;

if (myObject != null)
    // Do Something
```

This will normally be used if you can't know if you really got this kind of type. So simply try to cast it and if it is not possible, simply give a null back. A common example would be if you have to do something only if some interface is fullfilled:

```
var disposable = source as IDisposable;

if(disposable != null)
    disposable.Dispose();
```

Also the `as` operator can't be used on a `struct`. This is simply because the operator wants to return a `null` in case the cast fails and a `struct` can never be `null`.

#### [Type check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is)

```
var isMyType = source is MyType;
```

This is rarely correctly used. This type check is only useful if you only need to know if something is of a specific type, but you don't have to use that object.

```
if(source is MyType)
   DoSomething();
else
   DoSomethingElse();
```

#### [Pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching)

```
if (source is MyType myType)
    DoSomething(myType);
```

Pattern matching is the latest feature within the dotnet framework that is relevant to casts. But you can also handle more complicated cases by using the [switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#using-pattern-matching-switch-statements) and the [when clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching#when-clauses-in-case-expressions):

```
switch (source)
{
    case SpecialType s when s.SpecialValue > 5
        DoSomething(s);
    case AnotherType a when a.Foo == "Hello"
        SomethingElse(a);
}
```

Comment: Is compiler doing a "is" check before soft cast ( as) ?

Comment: thanks for the link. it was helpful @Oliver

Comment: Perhaps you should also mention that you cannot use `as` for struct types.

Comment: Since C# 7 you can use [Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching): `if (source is IDisposable disposable) disposable.Dispose();`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes: Yes you're right. Just updated my answer.

Comment: @vrnithinkumar: This could help to answer your question: https://ericlippert.com/2010/09/16/is-is-as-or-is-as-is/

Answer (score 9):

I think this is a good question, that deserves a serious and detailed answer. Type casts is C# are a lot of different things actually.

Unlike C#, languages like C++ are very strict about these, so I'll use the naming there as reference. I always think it's best to understand how things work, so I'll break it all down here for you with the details. Here goes:

**Dynamic casts and static casts**

C# has value types and reference types. Reference types always follow an inheritance chain, starting with Object.

Basically if you do `(Foo)myObject`, you're actually doing a *dynamic cast*, and if you're doing `(object)myFoo` (or simply `object o = myFoo`) you're doing a *static cast*.

A *dynamic cast* requires you to do a type check, that is, the runtime will check if the object you are casting to will be of the type. After all, you're casting down the inheritance tree, so you might as well cast to something else completely. If this is the case, you'll end up with an `InvalidCastException`. Because of this, dynamic casts require runtime type information (e.g. it requires the runtime to know what object has what type).

A *static cast* doesn't require a type check. In this case we're casting up in the inheritance tree, so we already *know* that the type cast will succeed. No exception will be thrown, ever.

*Value type casts* are a special type of cast that converts different value types (f.ex. from float to int). I'll get into that later.

**As, is, cast**

In IL, the only things that are supported are `castclass` (cast) and `isinst` (as). The `is` operator is implemented as a `as` with a null check, and is nothing more than a convenient **shorthand notation** for the combination of them both. In C#, you could write `is` as: `(myObject as MyFoo) != null`.

`as` simply checks if an object is of a specific type and returns null if it's not. For the *static cast* case, we can determine this compile-time, for the *dynamic cast* case we have to check this at runtime.

`(...)` casts again check if the type is correct, and throw an exception if it's not. It's basically the same as `as`, but with a throw instead of a `null` result. This might make you wonder why `as` is not implemented as an exception handler -- well, that's probably because exceptions are relatively slow.

**Boxing**

A special type of cast happens when you `box` a value type into an object. What basically happens is that the .NET runtime copies your value type on the heap (with some type information) and returns the address as a reference type. In other words: it converts a value type to a reference type.

This happens when you have code like this:

```
int n = 5;
object o = n; // boxes n
int m = (int)o; // unboxes o
```

Unboxing requires you to specify a type. During the unboxing operation, the type is checked (like the *dynamic cast* case, but it's much simpler because the inheritance chain of a value type is trivial) and if the type matches, the value is copied back on the stack.

You might expect value type casts to be implicit for boxing -- well, because of the above they're not. The only unboxing operation that's allowed, is the unboxing to the exact value type. In other words:

```
sbyte m2 = (sbyte)o; // throws an error
```

**Value type casts**

If you're casting a `float` to an `int`, you're basically *converting* the value. For the basic types (IntPtr, (u)int 8/16/32/64, float, double) these conversions are pre-defined in IL as `conv_*` instructions, which are the equivalent of bit casts (int8 -> int16), truncation (int16 -> int8), and conversion (float -> int32).

There are some funny things going on here by the ways. The runtime seems to work on multitudes of 32-bit values on the stack, so you need conversions even on places where you wouldn't expect them. For example, consider:

```
sbyte sum = (sbyte)(sbyte1 + sbyte2); // requires a cast. Return type is int32!
int sum = int1 + int2; // no cast required, return type is int32.
```

Sign extension might be tricky to wrap your head around. Computers store signed integer values as 1-complements. In hex notation, int8, this means that the value -1 is 0xFF. So what happens if we cast it to an int32? Again, the 1-complement value of -1 is 0xFFFFFFFF - so we need to propagate the most significant bit to the rest of 'added' bits. If we're doing unsigned extensions, we need to propagate zero's.

To illustrate this point, here's a simple test case:

```
byte b1 = 0xFF;
sbyte b2 = (sbyte)b1;
Console.WriteLine((int)b1);
Console.WriteLine((int)b2);
Console.ReadLine();
```

The first cast to int is here zero extended, the second cast to int is sign extended. You also might want to play with the "x8" format string to get the hex output.

For the exact difference between bit casts, truncation and conversion, I refer to the [LLVM documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html) that explains the differences. Look for `sext`/`zext`/`bitcast`/`fptosi` and all the variants.

**Implicit type conversion**

One other category remains, and that's the conversion operators. MSDN details how you can overload the [conversion operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx). Basically what you can do is implement your own conversion, by overloading an operator. If you want the user to explicitly specify that you intend to cast, you add the `explicit` keyword; if you want implicit conversions to happen automagically, you add `implicit`. Basically you'll get:

```
public static implicit operator byte(Digit d)  // implicit digit to byte conversion operator
{
    return d.value;  // implicit conversion
}
```

... after which you can do stuff like

```
Digit d = new Digit(123);
byte b = d;
```

**Best practices**

First off, understand the differences, which means implementing small test programs until you understand the distinction between all of the above. There's no surrogate for understanding How Stuff Works.

Then, I'd stick to these practices:

- The shorthands are there for a reason. Use the notation that's the shortest, it's probably the best one.
- Don't use casts for static casts; only use casts for dynamic casts.
- Only use boxing if you need it. The details of this go well beyond this answer; basically what I'm saying is: use the correct type, don't wrap everything.
- Notice compiler warnings about implicit conversions (f.ex. unsigned/signed) and *always* resolve them with explicit casts. You don't want to get surprises with strange values due to sign/zero extension.
- In my opinion, unless you know exactly what you're doing, it's best to simply avoid the implicit/explicit conversion -- a simple method call is usually better. The reason for this is that you might end up with an exception on the loose, that you didn't see coming.

Answer (score 1):

With the second method, if the cast fails an exception is thrown.

When casting using `as`, you can only use reference types. so if you are typecasting to a value type, you must still use `int e = (int) o;` method.

a good rule of thumb, is : if you can assign null as a value to the object, you can type cast using `as`.

that said, null comparison is faster than throwing and catching an exception, so in most cases, using `as` should be faster.

I can't honestly say with certainty if this applies with your `is` check in place though. It could fail under some multi threading conditions where another thread changes the object you're casting.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary but still o is not casted to Employee , Right ?

Comment: Bar multi-threaded stuff, how is the cast in the second method going to fail?

Comment: @Rawling multithreading can be the only way to get it to fail, i think.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `as` (safe-cast) operator if I need to use the object after casting. Then I check for null and work with the instance. This method is more efficient than `is` + explicit cast

> In general, the as operator is more efficient because it actually returns the cast value if the cast can be made successfully. The is operator returns only a Boolean value. It can therefore be used when you just want to determine an object's type but do not have to actually cast it.

(more information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488006.aspx)).

I am *not sure* about it but I think that `is` is using `as` under the hood and just returns if the object after casting is null (in case of *reference types*) / an exception was thrown (in case of *value types*) or not.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's a matter of taste and specifics of problem that you're dealing with. Let's have a look at two examples with generic methods.

For generic method with 'class' constraint (the safest approach with double cast):

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T myParameter) where T : class
{
   if(myParameter is Employee)
   {
      // we can use 'as' operator because T is class

      Employee e = myParameter as Employee;
      //DO stuff
   }
}
```

Also you can do someting like this (one cast operation here but defined variable of type that may or may not be correct) :

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T myParameter) where T : class
{
   Employee e;
   if((e = myParameter as Employee) != null)
   {
      //DO stuff with e
   }
}
```

For generic method with 'struct' constraint :

```
public void MyMethod<T>(T myParameter) where T : struct
{
   if(myParameter is int)
   {

      // we cant use 'as' operator here because ValueType cannot be null
      // explicit conversion doesn't work either because T could be anything so :

      int e = Convert.ToInt32(myParameter); 

      //DO stuff
   }
}
```

Simple scenario with explicit cast:

```
int i = 5;
object o = (object)i;  // boxing
int i2 = (int)o;       // unboxing
```

We can use explicit cast here because we are 100% sure of what types do we use.

Comment: Your first code examlple does try to cast twice, call as first and check for null instead. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182271.aspx

Comment: @Console Thanks, this is an option too, i've just added it to my updated answer, but it's not always a good one because it requires to define variable that may not be of correct type before doing this cast. And what if we have 100 types ?